# Ways of implementing IPC between an IDE and a compiled program

Tags: mono, ipc, jit, compiler-construction

**The context**

I am developing a compiler/interpreter which converts code from language **X** into a form of IL Assembly which is then compiled using mono's `ilasm` utility.

**The problem**

In my language I have implemented a specific feature which allows the compiled program to make changes to the GUI of the IDE *at runtime*.

This means that a program compiled with this tool can during execution change the text of a certain label, or rename the window, possibly change the whole layout of the window, e.t.c.

The problem that arises immediately is that communication between the compiled program and the IDE of some form has to take place. Since there is a limit of what is possible to alter in the IDE, it is sufficient to send back instructions on how to alter the GUI via messages of a form such as `action: params`

This communication, however, needs to be fairly fast, and from reading various other StackOverflow answers, I've come to the conclusion that there are three basic methods for accomplishing this:

1. Use Sockets
2. Use Named Pipes in Linux
3. Use Shared Memory

I couldn't really find a satisfactory comparison of the three methods however, and furthermore I am not completely sure the last (towards which I am currently leaning) is the best, since I've heard many people referring to it as `unsafe`.

To sum it up, what I'm looking for are suggestions on what is probably the safest, fastest and most practical method I can use in this context.

Comment: Pick one, whatever you are most comfortable with.  Sounds like none, don't pick shared memory.

Comment: You need to define "fairly fast". JetBrains chose RESTful services for Project Rider, as well as VSCode/OmniSharp. So I think for you, there is really no need to use other risky options. Micro services is such a popular concept.

Comment: Interesting @LexLi, I will certainly consider that advice.